# How to get Count in Hibernate 5 CriteriaBuilder with criteria condition

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-5.x

When I checked below code I got the count of all record. not condition wise.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
    countQuery.select(builder.count(countQuery.from(ViewEmployees.class)));
    Long q1 = getCurrentSession().createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
```

I want to get the count with criteria condition.
like this code

```
CriteriaQuery<ViewEmployees> query = builder.createQuery(ViewEmployees.class);

        Root<ViewEmployees> root = query.from(ViewEmployees.class);

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        // Equal Query
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(searchConditions.getCode())) {
            predicates.add(builder.and(builder.equal(root.get("code"), searchConditions.getCode())));
        }
```

Hibernate older version it was working with below code.

```
Criteria criteria = getApplicationEventConditions(searchCond);
        SearchTotals searchTotals = new SearchTotals();
        ProjectionList p1 = Projections.projectionList();
        p1.add(Projections.rowCount());
        criteria.setProjection(p1);
        List l = criteria.list();
        searchTotals.setTotalSize((Long) l.get(0));
```

Can you please anyone help me to solve this with CriteriaBuilder.